# Validar si existe el id en la base de datos, si existe hacer un update y si no existe hacer el inser into - PHP y postgresql

Tags: php, base-de-datos, postgresql, pdo

Buenas tardes como pueden ver en el titulo, quiero que a la hora de ingresar los datos a la bd de postgresql primero verifique que el "doc" exista, si es que existe hacer un update y si no existe hacer un inser into, lo e intentado leyendo en foros ejemplos pero no me a salido, aqui les dejo mi codigo en php:

```
public function InsertarHuesped( $tpcli, $pais, $doctp, $doc, $docexp, $name, $lastname, $email, $phone, $address)
    {
        $Conexion = $this->Bd->connect();
        $ResultSet = $Conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO cliente1 (tpcli, country, doctp, doc, docexp, name, lastname, email, phone, address)  VALUES (:tpcli, :country, :doctp, :doc, :docexp, :name, :lastname, :email, :phone, :address)");

        $ResultSet->execute(array(
        "tpcli" => "$tpcli",
        "country" => "$pais",
        "doctp" => "$doctp",
        "doc" => "$doc",
        "docexp" => "$docexp",
        "name" => "$name",
        "lastname" => "$lastname",
        "email" => "$email",
        "phone" => "$phone",
        "address" => $address
        ));

        return $ResultSet;
    }
```

Muchas gracias por ayudarme compartiendo un poco de su conocimiento, buen día.

Comment: solo con if se puede  bueno yo lo hago con if()

Comment: deberias crear primero un select luego con el result de este verificar si trae registros,si los trae es x q existe alli mandas hacer el update  y sino haces el insert

Comment: Excelente, voy a probar eso y publico los resultados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que estas buscando se muy similar a un upsert (update + insert).
Si tu version de PSQL es igual o superior a la 9.5, podrias ejecutar algo muy similar a lo siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, field) VALUES (1, 'foo')
  ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET field = 'bar';
```

Comment: lo voy a probar, es que estaba haciendo los if(), pero si me sale con esto mucho mejor :D

Comment: Me funciono perfectamente, solo como dato extra, para que funcione correctamente el campo que sirve de id tiene que ser clave única, al menos en postgresql, Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, field2) VALUES ('valor_id', 'val2' )
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field2 = 'val2'
```

Comment: cuando llegue a mi casa lo probare, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Juanda, aunque esta respuesta puede servir para resolver el problema expuesto, sería ideal que añadieras algo más de detalle: ¿qué es lo que hace el código que compartes? ¿cómo soluciona el probelma? Lee [answer] para más información y recomendaciones.